# How to get format specifiers in which a datetime string is parsed by Carbon::parse()

Tags: php, datetime, date-formatting, php-carbon, dateformatter

In Carbon PHP we have a method to parse string to date. if the string is a valid date string then i'd be parsed to a valid Carbon object. I'm curious to know if is there any way we could get the possible format string in which php determines the date would be. for example:

```
Carbon::parse("01 January, 2018");
```

then we'll get a valid carbon object.
My question is, can we anyway get "d F, Y" which is the actual format specifier php guessed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Method `parse` always return an instance of `Carbon\Carbon`. So you should either validate your string before:

```php
Validator::make(
    ['date_value' => $date],
    ['date_value' => 'date']
)->validate();
Carbon::parse($date);
```

or use `createFromFormat` method instead:

```php
if (Carbon::createFromFormat('d F, Y', $stringVariable) !== false) {
    // valid date
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but what I asked for is, get the format specifier of a datestring in which that datestring could be parsed into. as an example: for datestring like "01 January, 2018" i want "d F, Y" in return if possible anyway.

Comment: @AmiNirob Ah, sorry, for misunderstanding. I don't think it is possible to know using `Carbon`. You have to look for any other libraries or implement custom implementation

Comment: no, problem.  that's okay :). Can I please get a suggestion about other library ?

Answer (score 0):

`Carbon` extends the PHP `DateTime` class. The `Carbon::parse` method eventually passes the input down to `DateTime::__construct` which parses it as described in the PHP Manual [Supported Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).